# How to use "IN" operator with several columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is it possible this query:

```
select *
from   table t
where  (t.key1, t.key2, t.key3) IN ('a','b','c','d')
```

Condition with several columns and several values.

Comment: You are comparing 3 columns against 4 values. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split it in multiple statements. I didn't know whether you want to `OR` or `AND`, so I took `AND` in this samples:

```
select *
from   table t
where  (t.key1) IN ('a','b','c','d')
and    (t.key2) IN ('a','b','c','d')
and    (t.key3) IN ('a','b','c','d')
```

Or use a `join` and inline view:

```
select *
from   table t
join   ( select 'a' col
         from   dual
         union
         select 'b'
         from   dual
         union
         select 'c'
         from   dual
         union
         select 'd'
         from   dual
      ) x
on    t.key1 = x.col
and   t.key2 = x.col
and   t.key3 = x.col
```

Comment: IMHO, your first version with `AND` was more correct.

Comment: @tlecka: Need more help, or were the answers sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
from   table t
where  t.key1 IN ('a','b','c','d') OR
       t.key2 IN ('a','b','c','d') OR
       t.key3 IN ('a','b','c','d')
```